# Primary Video Controller

Tags: c#, wmi, hardware

I am trying to get the description of the computer's primary video controller. Right now, I'm getting back the logmein controller instead:

**VideoControllerDescription: LogMeIn Mirror Driver**

Here is my code:

```
private static string GetVideoControllerDescription()
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetVideoControllerDescription");
    var s1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_VideoController");
    foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in s1.Get())
    {              
        return oReturn["Description"].ToString().Trim();
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

I know I am getting back the first hit but how do I tell that it's not a software controller such as logmein or GotoAssist?

I want the model number, serial number, and description if possible.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this:

```
    private static string GetVideoControllerDescription()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GetVideoControllerDescription");

        var s1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_VideoController");
        foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in s1.Get())
        {
            var desc = oReturn["AdapterRam"];
            if ( desc == null) continue;
            return oReturn["Description"].ToString().Trim();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

It seems that the software adapters do not have an AdapterRam value.

Comment: Edit your question rather than add an answer

Comment: I answered my question, I wasn't asking another.